# Solving systems of equations and derivatives

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica, and I'm not sure how to solve a system of equations that include differentiation.

Given that f and g are differentiable functions:

```
f(x) < 0 for all x  
g(5) = 2  
h(x) = f(x) / g(x)  
h'(x) = f'(x) / g(x)  
Then g(x) = ?
```

(The answer is 2)

I didn't expect it to work, but I tried this:

```
DSolve[{f[x] < 0, g[5] = 2, h[x] == f[x]/g[x], h'[x] = f'[x]/g[x]}, g[x], x]
```

And of course it didn't work.

How would I do this?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate...

Comment: `Reduce[D[f[x]/g[x], x] == f'[x]/g[x], g[x]]`

Comment: @belisarius beat me to this, but...`h[x] = f[x]/g[x]; Solve[D[h[x], x] == f'[x]/g[x], g'[x]]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Why does that work?

Comment: And thanks for the answer!

Comment: It gives two expressions for the derivative of `h[x]`. Equating them and solving for `g'[x]` shows that `g'[x]` is 1. Might be easiest to see if you display `D[h[x], x]` (or maybe not...)

Comment: @Kuba Not much convinced about the worth of it, but I hate when easy questions remain unanswered. Done

Answer (score 2):

`Reduce[ ]` tells you something useful about those functions:

```
Reduce[D[f[x]/g[x], x] == f'[x]/g[x], g[x]]

(* (f[x] == 0 && g[x] != 0) || 
   (Derivative[1][g][x] == 0 && g[x] != 0) *)
```